# php dingo oauth2-server error

Tags: php, oauth, mockery

Hello im using this good php library to create my own Oauth2 Server so im trying to set some default scopes into the authorization request but i got this error, im looking for a solucion about 3 days ago.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method Mockery_0_Dingo_OAuth2_Storage_ScopeInterface::get() does not exist on this mock object'
```

This is my php code:

```
$server = new Dingo\OAuth2\Server\Authorization($storage);
$server->registerGrant(new Dingo\OAuth2\Grant\AuthorizationCode);
$request = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
$validator = new Dingo\OAuth2\ScopeValidator($request, Mockery::mock('Dingo\OAuth2\Storage\ScopeInterface'));
$validator->setDefaultScope(['accounts.profile.basic']);
$validator->requireScope();
$validator->validate(); // This line is what causes the error
$server->setScopeValidator($validator);
$payload = $server->validateAuthorizationRequest();
```

Github Dingo Oauth2-server: https://github.com/dingo/oauth2-server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the following: `$storage->createScopeStorage()`

```
$request = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
$validator = new Dingo\OAuth2\ScopeValidator($request, $storage->createScopeStorage());
$validator->setDefaultScope(['accounts.profile.basic']);
$validator->requireScope();
$server->setScopeValidator($validator);
$payload = $server->validateAuthorizationRequest();
```